# How would I call this method from another method?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

How would I call this method from another method:

I know how to link it up in IB etc, but how do I call it from the `aButtonPress` method I have below. I can't figure out the syntax.

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)button{


}

-(void)aButtonPress {    

    [self buttonPressed:nil];
}
```

thanks for help

Comment: You example looks like it would work.  Did you try it in the debugger?

Comment: It would surely work if you are not using `UIBarButtonItem`'s object any where in method body as you are passing it `nil`.

Comment: Incidentally, even though it's possible to do, it's not good practice for your code to call a UI handler.  If you need some common code that is run by the UI handler and also by other code, you should create a new method for that common code and just call that new method from the UI handler and also from other places.

Comment: what would be the syntax if I had to check a button.tag value from within the buttonPressed: method? What would I put instead of "nil"? thanks :)

Comment: Don't know why your second method is here when the first method is enough.

Comment: Instead of nil you need a reference to your button, which if its a property would simply be "self.myButton". If its an interface builder button, you need to create an outlet to get a reference to it.

Comment: @JohnWoods But for getting the clicked button's reference he need to get it again :). If button's target is `buttonPressed:` what is need of `aButtonPress`

Comment: It's fairly common to do this. If you access the button from inside the called method you can check for nil to skip the access, or else you'd have to obtain and pass the button pointer.

Comment: @TheTiger - `aButtonPress` is an EXAMPLE of how he would do the call.

Comment: @HotLicks - Yeah I know I just want to know that why he is not writing his code in `-(void)buttonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)button{}` method ? Sorry I could not understand his requirement here.

Comment: @TheTiger - It's fairly common, eg, to want to have the effect of having pushed a given button after a view loads or a download finishes or whatever.  So calling the "buttonPressed" method is quite frequently done, similar to what the OP is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way you are calling it would work. passing nil to the UI handler is OK. but put a null check to avoid unnecessary crashes/BAD ACCESS.

Comment: It's valid to send messages to nil in Objective-C. So the nil check is not needed, unless dereferencing explicitly.